# Multidimensional Poverty Index Subnational Geographies

Tags: shapefile, polygon

I am looking to merge data from Oxford's Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) at a subnational level with GADM boundaries, but I'm finding only about 60% match rates.

Does anyone know either the location of shapefiles corresponding to MPI subnational data or how the subnational location names in MPI were selected?

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about where to obtain it and/or how it was collated is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.